# Multiple Uploads PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload

I'm trying to use the dropzone JS plugin, and PHP to upload multiple files and then output each file url.

I have this so far:

```
  $upload_dir = 'files';

  for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $mainFile = $uploadPath.time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
     $mainFile_short = time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$mainFile)) {
    }
  }
```

I can't seem to make this work though, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: You're just ASSUMING that uploads always succeed. Bad assumption. ALWAYS assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason...

Comment: Along with what MarcB says about checking the `error` value, check your server logs for errors, and check to see if you are getting errors on the client side (dev tools console). Other than that we need more info like: is your JS making a valid ajax POST request? Are you giving Dropzone valid file objects? Are your files larger than the max upload / max post size

Comment: Mmm, this is an example of where debugging like var_dump, print_r and die come in handy. Just a quick check as well enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$img = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_dir = 'files';

if(!empty($img))
{
    $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);
    print_r($img_desc);

    foreach($img_desc as $val)
    {
        $tempFile = $val['tmp_name'];

        $uploadPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        $mainFile = $uploadPath.time().'-'. $val['name'];
        $mainFile_short = time().'-'. $val['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$mainFile)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$val` or `$var` ?

Comment: $val :) Sorry, my mistake

Comment: $val["name"] or change $val to $var in loop.

Comment: Could you add some text to tell how this code will solve the OP issue, please ?

Comment: I can get this to print the array with the upload files information if I just do $img_desc = $img, but it's not moving the files to the new folder, it gives an error of Undefined index: tmp_name and name?